# What's the difference between runghc and runhaskell?

Tags: haskell

RWH suddenly started using runhaskell instead of runghc.  What's the difference?  As far as I can tell, they work the same.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`runhaskell` can run whatever Haskell interpreter you're using on your system—it does not necessarily have to be GHCi. For example, `runhaskell` could instead point to `runhugs` or `runjhc` or whatever, if appropriate.

Essentially, it's just a nice alias. By using it, you make it much easier to change which compiler you're using in the future. After all, having `runghc` run `jhc` instead would be confusing!